# Not able to convert to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I might be using wrong python terminology.
I have an array of 3 integer elements: month, date and year.
However, I am not able to print each individual element when concatenating strings.

```
import ssl
import OpenSSL
import time
import sys

def get_SSL_Expiry_Date(host, port):
    cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((host, 443))
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
    raw_date = x509.get_notAfter()
    decoded_date = raw_date.decode("utf-8")
    dexpires = time.strptime(decoded_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%Sz")
    bes = dexpires.tm_mon,dexpires.tm_mday,dexpires.tm_year
    print (bes)
    #print(bes[0]+"/"+bes[1]+"/"+bes[2])

domain = sys.argv[1]
port = 443
get_SSL_Expiry_Date(domain, port)
```

If I uncomment line 14, I get an error:

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

I am trying to get the date in this format (all strings):  `Month/Date/Year`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
print(time.strftime("%m/%d/%y",dexpires))
```

See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

In general  python modules usually contain all kinds of reformatting functions you don't have to reinvent them.

Example:

```
>>> dexpires=time.strptime('20180823131455z','%Y%m%d%H%M%Sz')
>>> dexpires
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=13, tm_min=14, tm_sec=55, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=235, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strftime('%m/%d/%y',dexpires)
'08/23/18'
>>>
```

Comment: i get this error when i try this solution:
AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: @Bes Sorry, yes, you had to call module function, not the function of the particular time object. Changed the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `format()` method to handle it (much cleaner also):

```
print("{0}/{1}/{2}".format(bes[0],bes[1],bes[2]))
```

<sub>...or further simplified (thanks Anton)</sub>

```
print("{0}/{1}/{2}".format(*bes))
```

↳ [Python String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert int values to string than only you are able to concave them.
   You can use `str()` inbuilt method

```
print(str(bes[0])+"/"+ str(bes[1])+"/"+ str(bes[2]))  #convert int to str first.
```